# How to verify the node value and based on condition log the value?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having xml files which has following structure.

```
 <NodeData>
      <XPath>//VersionInfo/VersionList[Name = "FileCopy"]</XPath>
      <Node>
        <VersionList xmlns="">
          <Name>Core_FileCopy</Name>
          <Version>10.21.1.3</Version>
        </VersionList>
      </Node>
    </NodeData>
```

I am taking the values version and Name and store them in log file.

```
    $FileList= Get-Childitem -path "Z:\XmlFiles" -Include "*.xml" -recurse | ?{$_.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]} 
    $LikeArray = @("10.21.*","10.20.*","10.11.*")

    Foreach ( $File in $Filelist ) { 

        "Processing file $File.FullName"
        $xmldata= [xml] (Get-content $File.FullName);  
        $VersionLists = $xmldata.SelectNodes("//VersionList")    # Get the versionlist node

        # If it has VersionList node
        If ( $VersionLists -ne $null) {

            Foreach ($VersionList in $VersionLists) { 
$VersionList | Select Version | Where-Object {$_ -notlike $LikeArray }
            }

        }
    }
```

But I need to store both name and version only if it does not have the version numbers

> ("10.21.*","10.20.*","10.11.*).

I have modified my condition but still it displays all the version number

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you want.

```
$FileList= Get-Childitem -path "Z:\XmlFiles" -Include "*.xml" -recurse | ?{$_.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]} 
$LikeArray = @("10.21","10.20","10.11")
Foreach ( $File in $Filelist ) { 
        "Processing file $File.FullName"
        $xmldata= [xml] (Get-content $File.FullName);  
        $VersionLists = $xmldata.SelectNodes("//VersionList")    # Get the versionlist node
        Foreach ($VersionList in $VersionLists) { 
         if ( $LikeArray -notcontains $VersionList.Version.substring(0,5)) {
                    $VersionList | select Name, Version 
               }
        }
}
```